# Is there any line limitation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

is there any limitation on number of lines a javascript file can have?

Answer (score 15):

10<sup>121</sup> / 8

Since 10<sup>121</sup> is [the maximum number of bits in the universe](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/998867/files/0611115.pdf) and presumably you would do 8-bit encoding of your javascript, then even if the whole universe was filled with nothing else then your blank javascript file there could be no more then 11.25e120 lines in it.

TL;DR No there is no limit.

Comment: But if you are using all the bits, how is your computer going to try to run the file?  Surely it should be (10^121/8)-(bits to run computer)

Comment: This is also wrong on the fact that data compression is possible, aside from the fact that IE can only execute a fixed number of JS VM instructions.

Comment: @Tom Nothing was said about having a computer to run it ;) Incidently, that's just rounding error (if you skim through the article it says that the maximum is "on the order of 10<sup>121</sup>".

Comment: Undoing the -1 for assuming too much in the question.

Comment: @Stefan a completely blank file that long would have a total of zero of VM instructions and would weigh almost nothing GZipped ;) Still proves my point that the limits are elsewhere then the number of lines.

Comment: the link is kind of useless since it's behind a login wall

Answer (score 5):

Nothing official, but the larger the file, the more the browser needs to download, parse and execute.

In fact, a common practice it to join multiple javascript files into one so only one browser connection gets tied up with downloading javascript. This is normally part of minification (which can include other steps such as renaming variables to short ones, removing whitespace etc...).

Comment: @Stefan - So, an IE limitation, not shared by other browsers or the language.

Comment: Undoing the -1 for assuming too much from the question.

Comment: @Eli - Quite right, seeing as @Stefan has decided single handedly what the question is about. +1 to you too :)

Comment: "You are absolutely wrong. There IS a limit in IE. – Stefan Kendall"  So what is it?? Spill it already!  :)  I hear there's a limit but no one seems to have a number and a good source. I have a source for [the CSS limits in IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx), but what about Javascript??

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's an actual line number limitation for a javascript file, but obviously the number of lines and amount of javascript code you have can greatly affect performance.

So, the fact that you're asking this at all  might be a reason to optimize and examine the code itself.  Perhaps splitting out certain code functions that aren't needed on every page into different files could ease the load.

Comment: +1, although performance and LoC don't really have a strong correlation - in fact, I can imagine that for some complicated function it might be faster to have a huge precomputed table of results than to calculate them in JS (trading space for CPU time). But you are correct that the file needs to be loaded and parsed, and if it's actually a 10MB of program code, then yes, there might be a reason for concern :)

Answer (score 3):

**Nope :-)**

The only limitation is the memory of the computer it is running on, or the software running the Javascript.  There are no such limitations in the design of Javascript.

**However...**

If you have tens of thousands of lines of code, you may wish to evaluate your design and refactor a lot of it as it *can* be a sign of badly designed code.

Comment: @Stefan, a theoretical limit or a actual limit that causes hindrance to any Javascript that exists?

Comment: It's an actual limit. I've hit it many times dealing with pages with large DOM data. It's not "theoretical", and I doubt you've dealt with IE much.

Comment: @Stefan, no need to get personal my friend.  You have simply interpreted the question differently to everyone else.  IE was not explicitly mentioned.  Also, your example, the large DOM data has stopped it, not the `number of lines in the Javascript file` as originally asked by the asker.  Please give an example of the `number of lines` in the file stopping IE and not the processing of huge amounts of DOM data.

Comment: Undoing the -1 for assuming too much from the question.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: You just don't know what you're talking about. You can hit this issue without a large DOM. The large DOM just makes it easy (jQuery selectors fall back on scanning in IE, so a couple selectors make you hit this pretty quickly).

Comment: @Stefan, I do know what I'm talking about, why are you saying that processing huge amounts of DOM data is proof that Javascript has a physical limit on the number of lines it can process?  It's a completely different issue.  One is asking how many `lines` a file can have, and your interpretation apparently is `how much data it can process`.  I guess we are interpreting the question differently, which is always the risk when it's so vague, but it's logical to infer these answers from the original question surely.

Comment: @Tom Gullen You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: This is getting standard for me now on SO, give an answer that happens to be similar to everyone elses, gets downvoted, get personally insulted, and everyone else seems to get 10 more votes lol.  If I'm doing something terribly wrong please let me know as it's getting frustrating now for me.  Maybe I just need some time off :S

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is, if you are running in IE you will find that a program that runs over more than 5,000,000 lines. IE thinks it may be stuck in a endless loop and a popup will prompt the user to either kill the script or continue...

Comment: This isn't number of lines, it's number of executed VM statements. If you had a tight inner loop with complicated regex, you'll hit this limit quickly, even if the script SHOULD execute in sub-ms.

Comment: And if you have a file with 10 billion lines with conditionals such that only 4 million will get run any time through, you're fine. There's no line limit, and downvoting all of the other answers is *wrong*.

Comment: Reading this in 2021. It's so good not to worry about IE anymore.